# Integration WhatsApp Twilio and DialogFlow (GoogleCloud)

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, whatsapi

I am trying to do the integration of dialogflow from GoogleCloud with twilio to work with WhatsApp. What I want is to send WhatsApp texts or audios and use these texts or audios with a chatbot in dialogflow. However, it seems to not be working because when I send a message through WhatsApp I get answers that are not set up not even in the default fallback intent, which I have changed.

For example, the chatbot gives wrong answers, like:

• Hi! How are you doing?

• I didn’t get that. Can you say it again?

• Can you say that again?

• Hi there!

• Greetings!

My settings in DialogFlow: [settings](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lhNsFSmaSMzyWdvkj_ctZuxgm-iBbDpN?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is your webhook getting called when you send a message? Can you see logs for it? How have you configured the fulfillment webhook?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @philnash hello! yes my webhook is called when i send a message, i see it from the logs, and i leave a settings video of my webhook here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QijJpkuBU-dkuGdJiZ9k3UadpI2Kj5xc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The error in the raw log showed that your function timed out, and that's why it used the default fallback response. Are you able to debug or log out from your function to see what the code is doing, and where it gets stuck?

Comment: @philnash more almost, I new in this... but I see that the program gets stuck always in the start of it, in the first intent, so I am going to do it again, reviewing each part of the code

Comment: Ok, let me know how you get on!

Comment: hey man, I debug it but it continue doesn't work; My chatbot receive audio in a part of it, do you know if twilio has an inconvenient with it? do you know where can i contact an support twilio agent?